# Is this memset-memcmp on a struct variable valid C?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, unspecified-behavior

Is it legal to `memset` a struct to some value, then compare it with `memcmp`?

```
struct S {
    // struct definition not relevant, but it has bitfields
};

struct S invalid_S;
memset(&invalid_S, 0xFF, sizeof invalid_S);

struct S value;
memset(&value, 0, sizeof value); // actual data read would be here

if (memcmp(&invalid_S, &value, sizeof(struct S) != 0) {
    /// operate on fields of value
}

struct S value2;
value2 = invalid_S;

if (memcmp(&invalid_S, &value2, sizeof(struct S) != 0) {
    /// operate on fields of value, which doesn't happen now
}
```

Is the above codes behavior well defined, undefined or implementation-specified? Does validity of above code depend on `struct S`?

The reason for having a struct filled with 0xFF, and then comparing it with `memcmp`, is this: I have a function which returns a bitfield struct which matches what I read from a hardware device, with no wasted bits or bytes, and I want an efficient way to report error (the device can never return all 0xFF bytes). I have fixed platforms and toolchains, where the code works now, but can I trust it to not break if I for example increase optimization level?

---

Verdict: While this code could be made to work if I made sure there are no padding bits, float fields etc possibly problematic, I decided to instead just set one particular struct field to a specific "impossible" value to indicate error.

Comment: What you can't trust across platforms is the exact layout of bitfields: *""Almost everything about bitfields is implementation dependent"* K&R page 150.

Comment: Your question is IMHO too general to get a useful answer. You should explain what actual compiler and platform you use, and what is exactly your `struct S`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yeah, but I decided on alternative, hopefully robust approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it legal to memset a struct to some value, then compare it with memcmp?

Yes, since all of [memset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset), [memcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp), [memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) are documented to work on arbitrary memory zones (provided the pointer and the size passed to them are pointing to a valid memory zone).

However, in some cases, that might not be meaningful. For example, if you `memcpy` from some *uninitialized* memory, you'll get garbage in the destination, and using that garbage might be [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You are using `memset` with `0xff`. In theory, you might have some implementations where a `char` is larger than 8 bits (but in practice that does not happen so you don't care).

You might in theory have some implementation having trap representations for integral value. In practice, that does not happen.

If you use `memcmp` on structures having [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) that might not work as you expect. You may want to dive into the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specification of your platform to understand how they are implemented (and bitfields might not be specified in your ABI and be compiler specific).

I believe that in practice you need to understand well the exact layout of your particular `struct` with your particular compiler. It looks like your code might be hardware specific, then you don't care that much about portability. So in practice your `struct S` is *very* relevant (perhaps avoiding bitfields in it would be "safer").

Comment: Note that padding bytes (or bits) within the structure have indeterminate values and while the `memset()` calls are not a problem, the `memcmp()` calls are not reliable because of them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Action which modify a structure using its type might arbitrarily change the value of bytes which don't represent structure members.  On the other hand, if code uses memcpy to make two copies of a structure without having done anything else to it in the interim, I think the copies should be guaranteed to compare equal unless or until one (or both) of them is modified.

Answer (score 3):

You say the function returns a “bitfield struct”. If you are truly returning a struct, that is, returning a struct by value, then no, the behavior is not guaranteed to be what you want. When a structure is copied, the implementation merely needs to reproduce the values in its members, not the actual bytes in its representation.

The same applies in your line `value2 = invalid_S;`.

Comment: Do you mean, for example, if there are padding bits, their values might change? Or something else/more?

Comment: @hyde: Padding bits and bytes would be the most common things that an implementation might not copy. But types can have values that are represented in multiple ways. For example, the number .3 might be represented, in theory, with floating-point representations equivalent to 3*10**-1 or 30*10**-2. That is, two different byte patterns might both represent .3. When a C implementation is copying a value, it is only required to produce the same value, not the same bytes. So copying a .3 that is internally 30*10**-2 might produce 3*10**-1.

Comment: Right. As this is known platform and only integers (code would need some work to be portable), only padding bits are of interest here. Alas, I think it's enough of a worry about really obscure future bugs, that I will reject this approach.